# How to edit a typo in excerpt?

Tags: excerpt

How do I edit a typo in an excerpt?

After the excerpt was created, I saw a word that needed to be edited. I don't know how to get to it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the excerpt set to hidden in the edit screen.

Open your post for editing, click the `Screen Options` in the top right corner of screen, and then check the `Excerpt` box.

[image: Screen options in the post edit page]

After that, you can see the excerpt as a box in the edit post screen.